# AngularJS seems to be cached in a symfony/angular stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, caching

From yesterday i'm blocked. I'm working on a symfony/angular project from last year and i can't understand why the JS of the angular seems to be cached.

When i modifiy the style or the html of the views that's work fine, but when i'm playing with the JS there is no change.

I tried to clear the symfony cache, and the browser cache, to disable the browser cache, to change the browser, to modify/comment/delete the angular controller but no way to interact with the JS.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you hosting Symfony?